# custom list item vertical divider doesn't draw

Tags: android

This is what my custom list item should look like.

[image: custom list item]

I'm having trouble with the vertical blue bar. The `TextView` "Folder 1" should determine the height of the list item. The blue bar should adapt to that.

It looks like this:

[image: how it displays]

It only works correctly when the height is specified as a absolute value like `35dp`:

[image: fixed width]

I cannot understand why `match_parent` doesn't work in this context. Is there a better workaround?

layout.xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/img_color_folder"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_title_folder"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img_color_folder"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="Folder"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_notebook_count"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:text="15 Items"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

colors.xml:

```
<resources>
    <color name="blue">#FF0000FF</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: Show your java. The blue bar can't adapt to a height that is dynamic unless you measure the height of the list item, then set those layout params to that bar. - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.MeasureSpec.html

Comment: Another way, not as elegant, you could draw a 9patch image that has the blue bar on the left. Set your list item background to the 9patch image. It will resize everything for you.

Comment: @BingHammer java code is just inflating the xml via `LayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem, null)`

Comment: That probably won't be enough. You will need to inflate your list item, then measure the height. Set that height to your bar. Then `invalidate()` the view to refresh it.